# Sorting two-dimensional array by date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date-sorting

Is there a way I can sort the following array into the correct chronological order ?

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => Sat, 12 Feb 2011 16:55:13 -0500
        [title] => Product 1
        [link] => http://blabla/product-1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => Sat, 25 Sep 2010 17:52:24 -0400
        [title] => Product 2
        [link] => http://blabla/product-2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => Sun, 05 Dec 2010 17:41:32 -0500
        [title] => Product 3
        [link] => http://blabla/product-3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [date] => Sun, 28 Nov 2010 09:14:39 -0500
        [title] => Product 4
        [link] => http://blabla/product-4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [date] => Tue, 07 Dec 2010 18:43:45 -0500
        [title] => Product 5
        [link] => http://blabla/product-5
    )
```

The array, from a rss feed, comes to me like this.

I would like to sort the array in chronological order (based on [date] obviously) : *Product 1, Product 5, Product 3, Product 4, Product 2*

In order to be able to do display the latest products in the real order (not in the strange order they gave me ! - btw, fake products names, the order is really totally *random*)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use usort: http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/function.usort.php

You write a comparison function that compares two "elements" (in this case, your date strings), and returns the correct order for them.

Edit: you could use strtotime: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php to convert the date string to a timestamp, and then return the comparison of the resulting timestamps.

Comment: Yep, I am using usort but I can't find the right & correct comparison function ! (I am not really used to use theses functions with date)

Comment: @Max: you create your own function like this: `function compareByDate($item1, $item2) { return strtotime($item1['date']) - strtotime($item2['date']); }` , and pass the name (`compareByDate`) to usort.

Comment: added more info on comparing the dates

Comment: Hoo.. makes sense with strtotime now ! :) Thanks a lot !! It is just perfect !

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort) to order the original array according to the order of a sorted array of *date* values:

```
$keyValues = array();
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $keyValues[] = strtotime($item['date']);
}
sort($keyValues);
array_multisort($arr, $keyValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use usort function . 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php